# Encrypt String (of only digits) into another String (of only digits)

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I am using C#. I want to be able to take text from a user, then validate it as only integers.  If I choose to convert the String to int/long, I lose leading zeroes. I want to keep the leading zeroes. My plan is to keep this user input text as a String.

**I want to encrypt this String (of only digits), so that the result ciphertext is also a String of digits.**  Is there an easy way to do this in C#?  Is it even possible to do this?  Are there any alternatives?  Can I have examples if it is possible?

Example input:  "00123123678954"

Example output (after encryption):  "0129021398013"

Some requirements:

- The String length can vary from 12-19 (this length may
  change in the future). I want symmetric encryption. We can keep the
  encryption simple by using a single key and a XOR function (for
  now...I do want to improve it). I'm more worried about the
  format-preservation and how to do that.
- *String of digits* means a String of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, or
  any combination of those concatenated together.
- This question is referring to format-preserving encryption. 
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption

For those interested, I currently do the following (I don't have code on this machine...I'll put it up later):

1. Receive user input as String INPUT.
2. Convert INPUT to ulong (UInput).
3. Create cipher ulong with simple encryption ->  cipherU =  (UInput + 1) ^ SECRET_KEY
4. Store cipherU inside a database.

The issue is I lose leading zeroes between step 1 and 2.  I don't want to lose these leading zeroes (ex. "00123" has two zeroes in the beginning where as "345123" doesn't).  I figured using Strings with only digits is the best way to keep the leading zeroes.

Comment: Ahhh, the constant down votes but no questions or suggestions in the comment section.  Good on you fellas.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What do you mean by separator?  Is "integerS" a class or just a term for String containing only integers?  The String length can vary from 12-19 (this length may change in the future).  I want symmetric encryption.  We can keep the encryption simple by using a single key and a XOR function (for now...I do want to improve it).  I'm more worried about the format-preservation and how to do that.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this in C#? [Yes]Is it even possible to do this?[Yes]  Are there any alternatives? [Yes]

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt it into a string of digits?

Comment: The leading zeros issue is already mentioned in the opening post...

Comment: What I mean is why not store the encrypted string as a byte array?

Comment: Requirements by lead and tech manager.  Can't argue with them

Comment: It would be nice if you'd show us what you've tried, along with some examples of your input and [expected] output. A clear, concise problem statement makes helping you easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [AES Crypto Service Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) and then store the output as a binary string representation of the byte array output.

I.e 12345 might encrypt into "1001001010110001"

Comment: I like this.  Is there an easy way to convert byte arrays to a binary string?  Would I have to convert byte by byte or is there a way I can convert the entire thing at once (pre-written methods in C# API)?

Comment: @MohammadS. You can use a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) to convert an array of bytes to bits.

Comment: Why use binary?  Base 10 would suffice, just represent the bytes as "000" to "255" and concatenate.